# Storage of variables and dereferencing them

Tags: c, casting, memory-address, pointer-arithmetic

Based on the following snippet in C

```
int c1,c2;
printf("%d ",&c1-&c2);

Output : -1
```

1. Why does this code not return a warning saying the format %d expects of type int but it's getting a (void *) instead.
2. Why does it return -1 as an answer(and not 1)? Even if it's subtracting addresses it should be -4 and not -1. When I change the printf statement to `printf("%d ",&c2 - &c1)` I get 1 and not any random value! Why?
3. If I change the printf statement as `printf("%d ",(int)&c1 - (int)&c2)` am I typecasting an address to an integer value? Does that mean the value of the address stored as hexadecimal is now converted to int and then subtracted?

Comment: 1)Type of the difference between the pointer is a signed integer.

Comment: 2) pointer2 = pointer1 + 1 : pointer1 - poiner2 == -1, pointer2 - pointer1 == 1

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: My bad, deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It's getting an `int`. Pointer-to-something minus pointer-to-something is an integer value (type `ptrdiff_t`). It tells you how many elements away are two pointers pointing into the same array.

2) As the two pointer do not point into the same array, the difference is undefined. Any value can be obtained.

3) Yes. But the "hexadecimal" part is incorrect. Addresses are stored in bits/binary (as are integers). What changes is the interpretation by your program. This is independent of the representation (hex/dec/oct/...).

Comment: 1.) Close. It is not an `int` but `ptrdiff_t` which is a signed integer type. Please edit. Here is the reference: `6.5.6 Additive operators ,para 9`

Comment: However print(&c2-&c1)  gives 1. Shouldn't it always be a random value since the behavior is undefined?

Comment: Undefined behavior means no guaranteed behavior. In this particular case, most platforms will just calculate the difference of the addresses anyway. Hence you will normally see the same value on a given platform.

Comment: That's a really good answer! Could you elaborate a bit on part 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple cases of undefined behavior here.

If we go to the draft C99 standard section `6.5.6` *Additive operators* it says (*emphasis mine*):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements. **The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its
>   type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the** 
>   header. If the result is not representable in an object of that type,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Although, what you have is undefined behavior since the pointers do not point to elements of the same array.

The correct format specifier when using `printf` for `ptrdiff_t` would be `%td` which gives us a second case of undefined behavior since you are specifying the incorrect format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

1) Some compilers do issue warnings for malformed `printf` arguments, but as a variadic function, the run-time has no way of checking that the arguments are of the type specified by the format string. Any mismatch will issue *undefined behaviour* as the function attempts to cast such an argument to an incorrect type.

2) You say the result should be -4 but that's not correct. Only arrays are guaranteed to have their pointers aligned contiguously. You cannot assume that `c2` is at `(&c1 + 1)`.

3) `(int)&c1` is converting the address of `c1` to an `int`. That's again, in general, undefined behaviour since you don't know that `int` is big enough to hold the pointer address value. (`int` might be 32 bits on a 64 bit chipset). You should use `intptr_t` in place of the `int`.

Comment: I think the downvote is wrong. This is actually a very good answer.

Comment: ... except that the first part is not correct (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: OK: a bit better now. Thanks for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

1) A void* is nothing but an adress. An adress is an number (a long). There, the adress is implicitly cast to an int.

2) In memory, your variable aren't store in the same order than in
your code ;). Furthemore, for the same reason :

```
int a[2];
a[0] = 3;
*(a + 1) = 5; // same that "a[1] = 5;"
```

This code will put a "5" in the second case. Cause it will actually do :

```
*(a + 1 *sizeof(*a)) = 5;
```

3) Hexadecimal is a number representation. It can be store in a int ! Example :

```
int a = 0xFF;
printf("%d\n", a); // print 255
```

I hope that i have answered your questions.

Comment: The first part is wrong. The difference is not a `void *`. It is an integer.